# How to call Soap Client PHP with urn?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi i have this WSDL that, when i test in soapUI, it works well. 
but i am having problems to call it from php soap client.

```
        <soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:urn="urn:uXXX">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <urn:Pesquisar soapenv:encodingStyle=
                 "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                 <active xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</active>
              </urn:Pesquisar>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

i am trying in PHP something like this:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($mywsdl);
$headers[] = new \SoapHeader('urn:uXXX', 'urn');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
var_dump($client->Pesquisar(['parameters'=>['active' => true]]));
```

PS: This soap, doens have authentication, because i am inside a server that have access to the soap server.